# How to add a .framework as dependency to a swift package in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to know if there is anyway to link a swift package against a framework like `SQLite.framework` in Xcode? I'm trying to make a swift package for a sqlite library wrapper.

Here is my current swift package manifest:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.1
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SQLiteDB",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "SQLiteDB",
            targets: ["SQLiteDB"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [

        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "SQLiteDB",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "SQLiteDBTests",
            dependencies: ["SQLiteDB"]),
    ]
)
```

Comment: Since there are several Sqlite wrappers for Swift on GitHub it must be possible, maybe take a look at those projects to see if you can get any hints?

Comment: Only one of them https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift has SPM installation. I'm trying to figure it out how it is working

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating my own Sqlite package by embedding the amalgamation sources of sqlite. This gives you the ability to have any arbitrary version of Sqlite in your apps.

Comment: How did you do this?

Answer (score 0):

With the Xcode 12 beta, you can do this if you update your swift-tools-version to 5.3, and then add a binaryTarget to your package's targets:

```
.binaryTarget(
    name: "Stripe",
    url: "https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/releases/download/v19.3.0/Stripe.xcframework.zip",
    checksum: "fe459dd443beee5140018388fd6933e09b8787d5b473ec9c2234d75ff0d968bd"
)
```